# Asterisk: How to implement outbound rate limiting (calls per second)

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, rate-limiting

My VoIP provider has limited cps. When my Asterisk exceed the threshold, provider sends SIP 503 response and call goes through spare provider. How to make a call to wait for a while and then proceed? I guess there is  should be some "locks counter". So a scheduler check this counter, pauses and awakes a call process. What is the preferable mechanism to do that? 
It seems a kind of AGI script that has as a parameter CallerID, which accesses the server. If the counter is exceeded, then the server pauses the call process through the ARI mechanism.
Any hints, ideas are appreciated

Comment: Also, you could check for the SIP return code (503), if the provider has a specific return code / message to signal the exceed of rate limit. Just sleep for 0.5sec and try again in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
[globals]
calls_per_sec=20

[OUTBOUND]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Rate Limited Calling)
 same => n,Set(GROUP()=${EPOCH})
 same => n,GotoIf($[${GROUP_COUNT(${EPOCH})}>${calls_per_sec}]?DELAY,${EXTEN},1)
 same => n,Dial(SIP/provider/${EXTEN})

[DELAY]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Half Second Delay)
 same => n,Wait(0.5)
 same => n,Goto(OUTBOUND,${EXTEN},1)
```

Taken from [Asterisk Community Board](https://community.asterisk.org/t/outbound-calling-rate-limit-or-queue-not-a-call-queue/74976/2)

Comment: Have huge potential to make asterisk not work at all. But yes, may work.

Comment: @arheops Why do you think this is not reliable?

Comment: Lets say you have 10 cps limit and have constant 15cps incoming. Additional 5cps will go delay context. And wait forever(okay, not forever, upto ACD/ASR, so like 1 minutes). In next second come enother 15, 5 go for wait. So after 1 minute you have  in waiting context near 300 calls. Maybe 100. Think what will be if you have real cps at 30 or 100. This crap will work only if you have real CPS less then target CPS*ASR.

Comment: It does not work if most of the outgoing calls fail immediately. Say, I have incoming 20 INVITE per second, 18 of them get congested (e.g. SIP 503) after Dial(). Only 2 calls persist (i.e. ringing, in progress, active etc.) in the epoch. It this case setting calls_per_sec = 5 with GROUP_COUNT check did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any realible way do that for asterisk.

You can count in AGI script, external app or check GROUP_COUNT(${EPOCH}@control).

You can limit CPS naturally in kamailio using ratelimit module.